# setText not changing or updating when button click

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get random character when the user clicks in button in textView, it works but when I click again it's not updating the random character in my textView. Below is my code.

```
 char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(26);
Random random = new Random();

char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
sb.append(c);
final String output = sb.toString();
    show_random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            letters.setText(output); //only shows one time and when I click again it's not udapting
        }
    });
```

How do I get random character in every button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place generation of a random character inside the `onClick()` function.

```
 char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(26);
 Random random = new Random();

 show_random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
        final String output = sb.toString();
        letters.setText(output); 
    }
});
```

If you want just a single character then do next:

```
    show_random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        letters.setText(Character.toString(c)); 
    }
});
```

You don't need `StringBuilder` in this code if you just want to randomly set one character.

Comment: dude, thanks it works but I only I want one character and when I click again it should show one, not two.

Comment: @nice_cat try `letters.setText(Character.toString(c));`

Comment: @nice_cat yeah.Legend! Thanks a lot :)